# Черная иконка меню в toolbar'е

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar, color

На всех устройствах с Android 4.4 и ниже (Minimum SDK 17 стоит) проявляется такая проблема: иконка меню черная. Для всего остального, что есть в Toolbar, я задал цвета в разметке или в коде и все стало нормально. А с этой иконкой прямо что-то не так...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, возможно вопрос является дубликатом другого, но решение, предложенное там, мне не помогло. Атрибут colorControlNormal действительно меняет цвет этой иконки, но он меняет и Background EditText'ов, а мне это совсем не нужно. Как это исправить?

item'ы меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_aboutapp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/aboutapp"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_floatbutton"
    android:title="@string/edit_action"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Меню инициализируется в onCreateOptionsMenu.
Разметка toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.churkin.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Его стиль:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что объявление и "перекрашивание" тулбара выполнялось после super.onCreate(savedInstanceState). Не знаю как это связано, но теперь всё работает правильно

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, вы изначально выбрали тему со светлым тулбаром, но задали ему темный фон (синий). В коде или еще где преопределили цвета всего чего можно, но система-то об этом ничего не знает. На светлом тулбаре все рисуется темным!

Поэтому, вернитесь назад и задайте тему с темным тулбаром, уберите всю свою кастомизацию и посмотрите что получится.

Comment: Тема с темным вроде как задана (DarkActionBar). Прикрепил стили к вопросу. Может потому что шаблон NavigationDrawerActivity?

Comment: Ок, тогда вопрос. Вы сам этот элемент на тулбар добавляете? Или это библиотека appcompat скрывает ваши элементы, не умещающиеся на тулбар, под ним?

Comment: Меню инфлэйтится в главном активити. Насчет скрывает или не скрывает - сам вроде как задал что скрывать, а что нет. Вспомнил, что у toolbar отдельный xml файл есть... И сразу понял, что его тема немного другая, нежели основная. Добавил

Comment: Ну простите, тут уж дальше сами в этом зоопарке тем разбирайтесь :) Идею я вам подал, и похоже что она верная.

Comment: Хорошо, буду копать в этом направлении )

Comment: Дело не в темах 100%. В стандартном шаблоне с NavigationDrawer все отлично. Сижу сейчас и сравниваю шаблон и свой код :D